# web-based interactive MAN pages

Tags: shell, man

So, there was this website where you type a unix command and it would break the command into its arguments explaining what does what. I suppose it was based on MAN, but I'm not sure.
I lost the bookmark, anyone knows it?
Thks!

Comment: Try looking here: https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+man+pages+online

Comment: I really did that. Also asked some friends that work on IT..

Comment: No, really.  Look at the Google Search I just linked.  There's a half-dozen pages there that match your description.

Comment: Then I was not very clear. I want a way more interactive MAN, one which does break the provided command and explains every argument passed, not the complete list, just the used ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the website I was looking for:

http://explainshell.com/

And this is an example:
http://explainshell.com/?cmd=curl+-I+website.com

This website is so beautiful.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I was just about to ask the same question... Sadly, this site doesn't show up on google.... The author deserves way more traffic and recognition.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a fairly good interactive page for `man` content.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/man/

[image]

Comment: This is not very different of typing man in the terminal. The website I'm looking for is way more straightforward. It debugs the type command considering its arguments.

Comment: Your original question was about the `man` content and less about shell command explanation. Sorry for the misunderstanding.